# django south: problems with path to django

Tags: django, django-south

The problem causes this error when I try to use south:

```
$ python manage.py schemamigration
You must provide an app to create a migration for.
$ python manage.py schemamigration myapp --initial
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '../myapp/migrations'
$ sudo python manage.py schemamigration myapp --initial
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
$ python
>>> import south
>>> import django.core.management
>>> south.__file__
'/home/mydev/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/__init__.pyc'
>>> django.__file__
'/home/mydev/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.pyc'
```

It seems to me that `manage.py schemamigration` generates an error message that appears to be returned by `schemamigration`. But `schemamigration` and other south commands cannot find django once they are called.

`'/home/mydev/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/'` is on my sys.path. The `/south` folder is a sim link to the actual south package which is in a `/dist-packages` folder. I did put a sim link in the actual `/south` folder back to the the django package, but that didn't solve anything.

What could be wrong?

Comment: in my experience, this problem seems to arise when there are issues with your `settings.py` file... not sure of what all to try, though. I assume `south` is in your installed apps? Can you tell more about your setup? Is Django in your `PYTHONPATH` (I assume so, since you could import it, but...)?

Comment: `south` is in my settings.py file. What more do you want to know about the setup? The first steps I took to debug this were 1) create a new virtualenv, 2) install south, 3) see if south could do something to the apps that are part of the project. At step 3, `south` gave the above errors. The problems after these steps are the same as before these steps.

Comment: Is there a reason to not install south in your virtual env?

Comment: I did install south in my virtual env

Comment: @Cole did the answer help you?

Comment: After setting up a new project, digging around etc, I did find it is the ownership, and the ownership structure of my project is confusing. Your point, thematically, is right on! Thanks.

Comment: One last note. The ownership confusion was caused by the ftp client, whose files are given unique ownership `vsftpd`. Adding the user to the user group associated with `vsftpd` solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to permissions and use of virtualenv. You got the 'permission denied' error as your current user does not have write permissions for this project.

You can change the permissions for the entire project and make you current user as the owner of all files and folders in the project

```
sudo chown -R <username>:<username> <project_folder>
```

When you tried running migration using sudo it was not able to find django package as it lies in the virtualenv which has been activated by normal user. I guess these steps should solve this incase you don't want to change the permissions.

```
sudo -i
source /<virtualenv_path>/bin/activate
```

This should activate the virtualenv for sudo and now you'll be able to access all packages in the virtualenv

I think you should go the permissions way

Comment: the problem was the ownership of some files by 'vsftpd`. I tried adding the user to this group, but that solution didn't work. Your first suggestion worked great. I had to use sudo with it.

Comment: oh yeah forgot to add sudo, glad it helped